# What is the minimal friction force required in order for a ball on an incline to roll without slipping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I read an article now and it confused me completely.  Since I thought I have read somewhere else a completely different solution.

You put a ball on an incline at rest.  What is the minimal friction force so that the ball rolls without slipping?

I thought there is a simple and easy solution.    All you need is that  the sigma forces in X axis would be equal at least to zero. Which is the minimum,  or else the friction could be stronger.

But I have read this article https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.feynmanlectures.info/solutions/roll_without_slipping_sol_1.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwig-tinj4DbAhWCBZoKHextDoEQFghtMBQ&usg=AOvVaw1T-CXiuqp0CtO1W2NNFzbY  and he has long calculations for it.

I don't really understand why????

I am trying to think about it and my solution seems perfectly correct.   There isn't any force that rotates the ball apart from friction.   So the ball will certainly rotate as long as it doesn't slip.  And it doesn't slip when the  friction is equal or stronger than the X component of the MG force of gravity.

Isn't it sufficient to say that MGsin(a)= F friction?

Isn't it enough?   Why are there so much complexity in the article?  And why is it correct?

Comment: The calculation in the article is very detailed. Which steps do you disagree with and why?

Comment: I don't even need and specifications.   I just want someone to explain why isn't MY  solution correct?   If you ask me, I basically don't understand anything from what is written.    Why do you need to calculate anything further beyond equating the friction force to X component of mg?

Comment: Well,  I thought for a second that I understood you.  But  I regretted it.   Picture a hoop on an incline,  why wouldn't it rotate?   The friction being equal to mg would only cause it to no slip.   But as far as the rotational movement is concerned the mg doesn't act at all the only force acting is friction which WOULD rotate the hoop.  I even remember that this is what I studied with similar example.

Comment: If the friction force equals $mg\sin\theta$ up the slope, and the component of gravity down the slope is $mg\sin\theta$, then the resultant force on the ball is zero. The ball does not accelerate. If placed at rest it will remain at rest. ... If the resultant force on any object is zero, its COM does not accelerate ($F=ma$). The object might rotate, but the COM does not accelerate.

Comment: Why?  The rotational force acting on the ball is only friction.   Mg sin a doesn't cancel it.    Them being equal only means it wouldn't slip.

Comment: The question asked for a roll with no slip

Comment: What do you mean by "object might rotate "? Can you possibly picture a ball that rotates around itself and not moving?

Comment: No, equal forces in the opposite direction cancel out. But we know the ball does accelerate (either roll or slip or both) so the 2 forces cannot be equal, as the article shows.

Comment: Yes an object can rotate around its COM without the COM moving.

Comment: They are not co-linear, but they are in opposite direction. There is a torque/couple, and therefore angular acceleration, but there is no resultant force, and therefore no linear acceleration of the COM. An electric dipole in an electric field rotates about its COM. There is a couple acting on it but the resultant force is zero.

Comment: There isn't such a thing as rolling and slipping together.   There is either a roll with no slipping or when a force downwards is stronger then there is slipping with no rolling

Comment: Yes there can be rolling and slipping together. Haven't you played ten-pin bowling? You can make the ball spin backwards while moving forwards. Perhaps what you means is that it cannot roll-without-slipping and slip at the same time. Of course not. ... Or on the incline if the slope increases the ball can start off rolling w/o slipping but then slip (while still rotating) when the slope is too much to prevent it.

Comment: Of course there could be but then the acceleration isn't  constant. Or that the ball is jumping and getting blows from sides or nipples of floor.  As long as something is just touching the floor  when a single force is acting there isn't such thing.  You can play with the equations and see.

Answer (score 0):

If the no slip condition is satisfied then the linear acceleration of the centre of mass of the ball is equal to the radius of the ball times the angular acceleration of the ball.

This means that there must be a net force down the slope on the ball and at the same time a net torque acting on the ball.

If $mg \sin \theta = F$ there is no net force down the slope and yet there is a torque on the ball about its centre of mass equal to $Fr$ where $r$ is the radius of the ball.
So there is no linear acceleration down the slope and yet there is an angular acceleration.

If there is no frictional force then there is a net force down the slope and the ball will accelerate down the slope but as there is no torque on the ball about its centre of mass there will not be an angular acceleration.

This shows that the required frictional force has a value between zero and $mg \sin \theta$.

The derivation has the net force down the slope, with the frictional force less than $mg \sin \theta$, causing a linear acceleration down the slope and the torque produced by the frictional force causing an angular acceleration each of the correct magnitude so that the no slip condition is satisfied.

Comment: So what would happen if  mgsinθ=F ?  Would the ball rotate in its place?  Since there is a torque angularly of friction only ?  Moment of inertia multiplied by angular acceleration.

Comment: There would be no linear acceleration of the ball but there would be an angular acceleration of the ball.

Comment: So I am asking what would happen?   Would the ball rotate?

Comment: The centre of mass of the ball would either be at rest or move down the slope at constant velocity and the ball would rotate with the angular speed increasing but this is not a realistic situation.

Comment: Sorry .  I am asking a simple question.  Would it rotate?  What do you mean at rest?  Would it rotate on its place?  You didn't answer.

Comment: The motion of the ball can be broken down into two parts. Motion down the slope and rotation.  If you condition is satisfied the ball will rotate with increasing rotational speed.

Comment: Jesus Chris.   I put a ball with no velocity on a slope.   Friction is equal to MGsin(a)   .   You said the ball wouldn't move.   Does it rotate around itself or not?  Yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it sufficient to say that MGsin(a)= F friction?

No, that is impossible.

- If $mg \sin(a)= f_s$, with $f_s$ being static friction, then all forces balance out along the incline. Then there can be no linear acceleration (due to Newton's 2nd law) and thus the ball wouldn't start moving at all. But we know that it *will* start moving - so clearly this is *not* the case. The forces do *not* balance out.
- Also, the static friction would never be *larger* than the weight component - because then there would be a net force *up along the incline*, and the ball would start rolling upwards. This also doesn't actually happen, so that also can't be true.

The true situation must be that the static friction is smaller than the weight component.

> Why are there so much complexity in the article? And why is it correct?

To solve it we must ask ourselves what is required for rolling without slipping. From the above we just know that the static friction must be smaller than the weight component - that is not specific enough. So, what else can we use?

Another indicator we can use is that the contact point is *stationary*! The part of the periphery that touches the ground does *not* move. (This is how we know that there must be static friction rather than kinetic friction).

- While the ball rolls down with a centre-of-mass acceleration $a_{cm}$, the rotation must correspond to a "counter-acceleration" of the periphery, so to speak; a "counter-acceleration" of the periphery so that the acceleration of the contact point cancels to zero. This happens to be achieved by a periphery acceleration of $a_{cm}$ relative to the centre. Then the top point accelerates with $a_{cm}$ forwards and the bottom point with $a_{cm}$ backwards relative to the centre. **Relative to the ground**, the top point then accelerates with $a_{cm}+a_{cm}=2 a_{cm}$ and the bottom point - the contact point - with $a_{cm}-a_{cm}=0$.

Perfect. Now we have a clear indicator that only is the case when we have rolling without slipping. Since the periphery follows the relation $a=\alpha r$, then we can use: $$a_{cm}=\alpha r$$ as out indicator. When we plug that into some formulas somewhere, then those formulas only hold true for rolling without slipping.

Now we only need some formulas. Since we are looking for $\mu_s$, then I would set up some Newton's laws, either linearly or rotation-wise, and step by step see if I can isolate $\mu_s$ and plug in the above expression and remove all unknowns.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77446/discussion-on-answer-by-steeven-what-is-the-minimal-friction-force-required-in-o).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the minimal friction force required in order for a ball on an incline to roll without slipping?

As you have suggested in a comment, one way of looking at this is to model the ball as a regular polygon, and to gradually increase the number of sides.

For any polygon the object will slide if $\tan\theta \gt \mu$. This is a standard result found by comparing the component of force down the incline $mg\sin\theta$ with the maximum friction force $F= \mu N$ where $N=mg\cos\theta$ is the normal reaction.

However, as the slope angle $\theta$ is increased the disk could topple before it reaches the condition for sliding if its COG falls outside of its base. Toppling may lead to subsequent tumbling or rolling down the incline. There might also be some sliding depending on dynamical factors, which are difficult to analyse but less significant as the number of sides $n$ gets larger. See [Motion of a Hexagonal Pencil on an Inclined Plane](https://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/0706/0706.3431v2.pdf).

A square disk will topple if $\theta \gt \frac{\pi}{4}$ provided there is sufficient friction to avoid sliding. So as $\theta$ is increased if $\mu \gt \tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1$ the disk will topple first and subsequently **tumble** down the incline. Otherwise is will slide before the toppling condition is reached.

A hexagonal disk  will topple if $\theta \gt \frac{\pi}{6}$. So as $\theta$ is increased if $\mu \gt \tan\frac{\pi}{6} \approx 0.577$ the disk will topple first and roll. Otherwise it will slide before the toppling condition is reached.

In general, an $n$-sided disk will topple (roll) first if $\mu \gt \tan\frac{\pi}{n}$. For $n=36$ the minimum coefficient of friction is $0.0875$. In the ideal case of a perfect circle ($n\to \infty$) the minimum friction can be vanishingly small.

Comment: So what happens when friction force is indeed equal to the force downwards?

Comment: With the n-sided disk, if $\theta$ is gradually increased from 0  then friction will equal force down slope, both increasing together, with nothing happening until either the object slides or it topples. If $\mu \lt \tan\frac{\pi}{n}$ then the friction limit is reached before the toppling condition is met, and the disk will slide. If $\mu \gt \tan\frac{\pi}{n}$ then the disk will topple (roll) before reaching the friction limit. For a perfect circle $\tan\frac{\pi}{n} \to 0$ so even a very small amount of friction is enough to make the disk topple before the friction limit is reached.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by topple.   I don't care about other disks. Only a perfect one.  Please explain why wouldn't it rotate?

Comment: Toppling is the same as rolling or rotating about an edge. ...  There are 3 things the n-disk can do as $\theta$ is increased : 1. remain at rest (when friction = force down slope), 2. slide (when friction $\le$ force down slope), 3. topple/roll (when also friction $\le$ force down slope). For an $n$-disk if $n$ is finite the disk is at rest (condition 1) initially. But if $n$ is infinite (perfect circle) then the disk topples (rolls) immediately even for very small angles $\theta$ and small values of $\mu$. It is never at rest, and friction is always less than  force down slope.

Comment: What does that mean? Isn't the friction is a fixed number each material gets?  Why can't I equate the mg  to the friction?

Comment: The coefficient of friction is constant. The static friction force increases as the slope increases. For the n-disk the friction force is initially equal to the force down the slope, up to some critical value of $\theta$, during which the disk is at rest (no sliding, no turning). But as $n\to\infty$ the critical angle up to which friction force = force down slope decreases until it is vanishingly small. Then even for infinitesimally small angles $\theta$ the friction force is less than force down slope.

Comment: So friction is a parameter of the slopness/steppnes as well?

Comment: Yes the friction **force** increases as the force down the slope increases - but only up to a limit. When that limit is reached, the friction force cannot increase any more, whereas the force down slope can keep increasing as the slope increases. When the limit is reached, the object starts sliding.

Comment: Of course I know that static force is just a max value that increases accordingly up to a certain point.  What I mean is, that it changes from one thing to another.  For a box you would have one value,  and for a ball a different one.  It's also depending on the surface whether it's slop or straight. Otherwise why does it always in this case of slope and ball necessarily the friction stays less than mg.   Which is all new and strange for me.

Comment: No, the coefficient of friction depends only on the nature of the two surfaces which are in contact. It does not depend on the shape of the objects, or their orientation in space (eg slope or curvature).

Comment: If the disk object (whether circle or n-sided) accelerates down the slope then friction force up the slope must be less than gravity force down slope. They are only equal when the object is not accelerating - eg when the n-sided disk is balanced at rest. The circular disk or sphere is always accelerating, it cannot be balanced at rest on a slope which is not horizontal, so the 2 forces are never equal for these objects.